# How to make an IsManager field in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

My question starts much like the question here [ [Easiest way to find IsManager in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740258/easiest-way-to-find-ismanager-in-sql) ] with an Employee table but with EmployeeIDs as the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
  (
     [EmployeeID]             [INT] NOT NULL,
     [FirstName]              [NVARCHAR](90) NOT NULL,
     [MiddleInitial]          [NCHAR](1) NULL,
     [LastName]               [NVARCHAR](90) NOT NULL,
     [SortName] AS ( ( [LastName] + ', ' ) + [FirstName] ),
     [FullName] AS ( ( [FirstName] + ' ' ) + [LastName] ),
     [ManagerID]              [INT] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_EmpInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [EmployeeID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  )
ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Manager] FOREIGN KEY([ManagerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeID])

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Manager]

GO
```

I now want to add a column to the table that will accomplish the IsManager functionality as described in the link above; basically if an Employee's ID is in the ManagerID column at all, their IsManager value would be [1], otherwise it would be a [0].

The CASE statement in the link above doesn't work as the definition for a computed column because sub-queries aren't allowed in computed columns.

I think I could do this with a TRIGGER, but I'm reluctant to do so, as every night an SSIS package updates the entire Employee table with data from a Peoplesoft database, and if a TRIGGER has to scan the whole table for every row's UPDATE, I think my SSIS package could take 3-5x longer to run.

I know I could do it with a script, but unless I ran the script every few minutes, manual updates to the ManagerID column (and yes, we sometimes have to do this) won't be reflected in the Manager's record until the script is re-run.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsManager(@emplID INT)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT CASE 
                     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ManagerID = @emplID) THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                  END
   )
END
```

and then use this function in order to add a computed column in your original table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee
   ADD IsManager AS dbo.IsManager(EmployeeID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add IsManager bit Column with default value as `0`

an update statement with a join would do the trick

```
Update E
    Set E.ISManager = 1
FROM Employee E 
     Join Employee M ON E.EmployeeId = M.ManagerID
```